# How can I set the exact position (0-100% position like in photoshop) of color stops on gradients in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app

In photoshop I can set the exact position using % of a color stop and it's opacity.  I need to do this in Sketch to make it a viable tool for our UX.  Is there a way to achieve this with the default gradient fill in Sketch, or with a plugin?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Why do you need exact positions for a gradient?  What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Why wouldn't someone want better/more finite controls over their gradients within Sketch?  Uneven gradients and designs tend to look sloppy and, well, unbalanced.  When working with multiple designers & devs on a project we need our graphics to be consistent and easy to make (just eyballing it takes more time to get right).  It's a total waste.

Comment: I ask questions like this when I suspect there is a deeper underlying reason for something which the OP may have forgotten to mention, because this often results in [XY-Problems](http://xyproblem.info/). It's not a criticism of your question. I was simply seeking clarity.

Comment: This comment section seems to highlight why UX is such a black hole for so many companies.

Comment: Hello @DenseEmptiness, welcome to GDSE. May I urge you to [assume good intent](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)? A lot of new users ask a question, then when receiving an answer go "yeah, but I'm actually trying to..." So excuse our apprehension. We'd rather get the full story first before investing time and energy answering questions.